# MVC complex data query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

I have a query as below :
`Table

1. London  flat
2. London  flat
3. London House
4. Paris   flat
5. Paris   flat
6. Paris   House
7. Paris   House`

I am looking to turn this to below object in linq. Anyone please help me.

```
 public class BrowseModel
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }

    public int FlatCount { get; set; }

    public int HouseCount { get; set; }

}
```

The result need to be like:

1. London 2Flat  1 house
2. Paris  2Flat  2 houses

Comment: Is that list of string that you convert into BrowseModel Type

Comment: It is a object. Imagine house object. flat and house are house type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if i haven't understood your question wrong you can try it like this

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        //Ignore above code
        List<Table> list = new List<Table>();
        //Suppose this what you db returns
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "London", HouseType = HouseType.Flat });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "London", HouseType = HouseType.Flat });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "London", HouseType = HouseType.House });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "Paris", HouseType = HouseType.Flat });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "Paris", HouseType = HouseType.Flat });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "Paris", HouseType = HouseType.House });
        list.Add(new Table() { TownName = "Paris", HouseType = HouseType.House });

        var result = list.GroupBy(o => o.TownName).Select(s => new BrowseModel() { TownName = s.First().TownName, FlatCount = s.Where(f => f.HouseType == HouseType.Flat).Count(), HouseCount = s.Where(h => h.HouseType == HouseType.House).Count() }).ToList();
    } 
}

public class BrowseModel
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }

    public int FlatCount { get; set; }

    public int HouseCount { get; set; }

}

public class Table
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    public HouseType HouseType { get; set; }
}

public enum HouseType
{ 
    House=0,
    Flat=1
}
```

I hope this will give you idea.